# No such file or directory with import

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm a beginner with Python and I'm not able to run anything with installed modules. For example I have very simple script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import killport

subprocess.run(["killport", "1111"])
```

but the result is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jklimcik/bin/infra-scripts/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.run(["killport", "1111"])
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'killport'
```

I have installed this module:

```
$ python3 -m pip show killport                                                                                                                     
Name: killport
Version: 1.2.0
Summary:
Home-page: https://github.com/dannysepler/killport
Author: Danny Sepler
Author-email: dannysepler@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /Users/jklimcik/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages
Requires: psutil
Required-by:
```

I'm using PIP. I've already tried to completely uninstall and reinstall it again.

```
pip3 --version                                                                                                                                     
pip 23.2 from /Users/jklimcik/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

What's wrong or what am I missing? I'm using Python 3.9.6 and running on MacOS, Apple M1

Answer (score 0):

1. check you install the package in the env you run the program

Answer (score 0):

I solved it finally and I'll keep it here as it can be useful for others.

I tried to reinstall `killport` and I noticed a warning:

```
$pip3 install killport                                                                                                                          
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting killport
  Using cached killport-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /Users/jklimcik/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from killport) (5.9.4)
Installing collected packages: killport
  WARNING: The script killport is installed in '/Users/jklimcik/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed killport-1.2.0
```

So I started to dig what it means and in the end [the solution is here](https://superuser.com/a/1538940/510868). I just needed to add PATHs into my `.zshrc` and it works after that.